# Phone returns after a few seconds to main menu

Tags: applications

Whatever I chose to do on my Android smartphone, after a few seconds it exits the application or option by itself and returns to the main screen. Any idea what could be causing this?
It is a BML GT-N7100 (SKU MH0693W) with Android 4.1.1

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! We're excited to have you here, but we'll need more information to help you. Could you please [edit] your question and add information like which phone you use, which Android version you have, how long you've had the problem, etc?

Answer (score 0):

If your phone has hard keys, it could be that the home or back key is stuck, making the phone think you're pressing it repeatedly. If this is the case, you'll need to get the phone seen to by a technician.

Comment: No hard key, the "back" key is as well touch-sensitive.